# string text with blank cells

Tags: excel, string

I am trying to string together text from cells across by row when some of the cells are blank. I also want to have commas separating the text from each cell but cannot figure out how to only have commas put in when there is data in a cell.

I have tried using variations of concatenate and stringing the text using A1&B1&C1 but nothing is returning the data in the format I want.

Is there a combination of nested formulas I can use that will return the data in the format I want?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? In 2016, you can do [`TextJoin()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c): `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,[range])`

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013 so the textjoin formula isn't available to me.

Answer (score 0):

The formula below could do the trick. Concatenate the val The trim would remove spaces from the ends, and the substitute would swap the space for the comma(space).

=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1 & " " & B1 & " " & C1 & " " & D1), " ", ", ")

Edit from the comments below - you could update the spaces between the quotes to be any character that does not appear in your cells. You would just have to the substitute formula to match. If you don't use the | character for example:

=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1 & "|" & B1 & "|" & C1 & "|" & D1), "|", ", ")

Comment: I tried this formula but some of my data has more than one word per cell and this formula inserts commas wherever there is a space within each cell. Any fixes for this?

Comment: Instead of " " between the ampersands you can use any character that doesn't appear in your text - just replace the spaces. Also replace the space in the second to last segment. For instance, if you don't use any \  or * characters, your formula could look like this: 

=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1 & "\" & B1 & "\" & C1 & "\" & D1), "\", ", ")
or 
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1 & "*" & B1 & "*" & C1 & "*" & D1), "*", ", ")

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution I had before the newer versions:

```
Public Function JOINCELLS(ByVal ref As Range) As String
Dim c       As Range
For Each c In ref
    If Len(c) > 0 Then
        JOINCELLS = JOINCELLS & c & ", "
    End If
Next
JOINCELLS = Left(JOINCELLS, Len(JOINCELLS) - 2)
End Function
```

Then, it's just `=JOINCELLS(A1:D1)`.